# DBSCAN one demension, finding core points

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

One of the practice quiz question(not homework) is asking to find how many core points in one dimensional points with given EPS and MinPTS. I thought DBSCAN should be used for only two dimensions. Any guidance is much appreciated.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvUoi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DBSCAN can be used on 1 dimensional data.

It's not particularly smart (just use Kernel Density Estimation instead) but why do you think this would not work?